# Why does my Measure-Object fail when my function has a second parameter?

Tags: powershell

The following function works:

```
function myFunc1($arr1)
{
    $arr1 | Measure-Object -Maximum
}  
myFunc1(@(1,2,3))
```

But when I add a second parameter, it does not:

```
function myFunc2($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $arr1 | Measure-Object -Maximum
}
myFunc2(@(1,2,3), @(1,2,3))
```

It gives me this error:

```
Measure-Object : Cannot compare "System.Object[]" because it is not IComparable.
At C:\Users\bob\Documents\test2.ps1:3 char:13
+     $arr1 | Measure-Object -Maximum
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Measure-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

All I did was add a send parameter, `$arr2`, and it broke the earlier code.  I do not understand why the addition of `$arr2` would affect calling `Measure-Object` on `$arr1`.

Comment: Don't call PowerShell functions with parentheses: `myFunc2(@(1,2,3), @(1,2,3))`.  Supply the parameters as if it were a cmdlet or a traditional command-line tool: `myFunc2 -arr1 @(1,2,3) -arr2 @(1,2,3)`.  You can usually leave out the parameter names: `myFunc2 @(1,2,3) @(1,2,3)`

Comment: That's it!  I've been spending too much time on python lately. :)